Crack in bathroom wall
I am working on my parents home from the mid 1930s in NY and while there are hairline cracks here & there, there's this big one in the downstairs bathroom where the tub is. This bathroom doesn't have a vent fan (does have a window) & hasn't been used for bathing lately - but certainly was in the past.
They had a 2nd floor addition put in about 20 years ago adding weight to the house - not sure if there is something major going on here, or is it safe to treat it cosmetically? My gut says the former, but looking for other opinions on the best path forward.


Was the addition properly designed or was it just added as a DIY project?  20 years ago I imagine they had to have permits and engineer design it.

The addition was properly done with permits & all back then.  Plumbing & electric is all relatively new (much of it done at that time 20 years ago, except this bathroom, which I'm still trying to figure out why).

Is the crack new, or has it been there a while?

The shape of the crack, plus it seems to have cracked the drywall(not the mud at seams), and the tiles seem to have sunken(unknown if new), makes it a bit more concerning than simple settlement cracks.

The age is a good question - they never use the shower, but my dad did try to patch it once (you can see it's painted over) but clearly it's still there. He thinks its fine, but I'm concerned if we should be calling a structural engineer.

@crip659 assuming the bathroom in question is original construction (based on the tile choices), so wouldn't this likely be a plaster wall, not drywall?  OP, can you confirm the actual wall construction?
